# Why can't I visualize charts in my ipython setup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Why can't I visualize charts in my ipython setup?
It just displays:

```py
Out[6]: <AxesSubplot:>
<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

See below for the full code. I took the example from the [pandas website](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/visualization.html).

```py
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 12 2021, 15:26:36)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.23.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   ...:
   ...: %matplotlib inline

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))

In [5]: ts = ts.cumsum()

In [6]: ts.plot()
Out[6]: <AxesSubplot:>
<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

Comment: have you tried with `plt.show()`

Comment: btw code is working as expected....try `plt.ion()` after that `ts.plot()`......if the problem continues then try updating `jupyter-notebook` or uninstalling and again installing it

Comment: `%matplotlib inline` is for a jupyter notebook, not an `ipython` console, so remove that line and then add `plt.show()` at the end. I'm voting to close this as caused by a typo / not reproducible.

Comment: None of the above recommendations worked.  Thanks anyway. I'll have to figure it out myself I guess.